# Raspberry pi 3 C++ Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspbian, member-functions

i have tried to accomplish using thread with Raspberry pi 3 with c++.

My C++ code:

```
thread t1(&salinecyObjectDT::colorBasedSegmentation, objDT, image, confParams.getHsvParams(), confParams.getSpectrum(), ref(binaryColorBasedFilter));                   
t1.join();
```

objDT is a instance of a saliencyObjectDT class. And it's hpp file is;

```
void colorBasedSegmentation(const Mat& image, const Mat& params,int spectrum, Mat& binaryFilter);
```

It's works well with my Windows machine but on Raspberry Pi 3 gives this error;

```
*In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from /home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (salinecyObjectDT::*)(cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)>(salinecyObjectDT, cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual, cv::Mat, std::reference_wrapper<cv::Mat>)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:140:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (salinecyObjectDT::*)(cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&); _Args = {salinecyObjectDT&, cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual&, cv::Mat&, std::reference_wrapper<cv::Mat>}]’
/home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:201:109:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (salinecyObjectDT::*)(cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)>(salinecyObjectDT, cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual, cv::Mat, std::reference_wrapper<cv::Mat>)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (salinecyObjectDT::*)(cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)>(salinecyObjectDT, cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual, cv::Mat, std::reference_wrapper<cv::Mat>)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2*
```

And maybe it will be required, CmakeLists.txt looks like this;

```
*cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(SaliencyMapBasedDetection)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    salinecyObjectDT.cpp
    salinecyObjectDT.hpp
    main.cpp)


include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
else()
       message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.$
endif()

find_package( OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED )

include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(SaliencyMapBasedDetection ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(
  SaliencyMapBasedDetection
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)*
```

Edit: because of function is memberfunction should i use **&objDT** while creating thread?

Edit2: when i use cref and ref result looks like;

```
    /home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:199:110: error: use of deleted function ‘void std::cref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = cv::Mat]’
      thread t1(&salinecyObjectDT::colorBasedSegmentation, &objDT, cref(image), cref(confParams.getHsvParams()), confParams.getSpectrum(), ref(binaryColorBasedFilter));
                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from /home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:456:10: note: declared here
     void cref(const _Tp&&) = delete;
          ^
/home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:209:110: error: use of deleted function ‘void std::cref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = cv::Mat]’
      thread t1(&salinecyObjectDT::colorBasedSegmentation, &objDT, cref(image), cref(confParams.getLabParams()), confParams.getSpectrum(), ref(binaryColorBasedFilter));
                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from /home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:456:10: note: declared here
     void cref(const _Tp&&) = delete;
          ^
/home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:242:110: error: use of deleted function ‘void std::cref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = cv::Mat]’
      thread t1(&salinecyObjectDT::colorBasedSegmentation, &objDT, cref(image), cref(confParams.getHsvParams()), confParams.getSpectrum(), ref(binaryColorBasedFilter));
                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from /home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:456:10: note: declared here
     void cref(const _Tp&&) = delete;
          ^
/home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:248:110: error: use of deleted function ‘void std::cref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = cv::Mat]’
      thread t1(&salinecyObjectDT::colorBasedSegmentation, &objDT, cref(image), cref(confParams.getLabParams()), confParams.getSpectrum(), ref(binaryColorBasedFilter));
                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from /home/pi/Desktop/saliencyBasedDetection/saliencyDetection/main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:456:10: note: declared here
     void cref(const _Tp&&) = delete;
          ^
CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SaliencyMapBasedDetection.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

**Solution: After i review my code and re-write with boost::thread in respect to boost::cref and boost::ref, it worked well...**

Comment: To pass references to a thread-function you need to use [`std::ref` and `std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) when creating the thread.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (clang++ 3.9.1 on Linux).  Saying that, it looks as if you're using g++ 4.9 which -- if memory serves -- had incomplete c++11 support.  Have you tried using `boost::thread` rather than `std::thread`?

Comment: G.M. i have realised this issue, and now i'm try to boost::thread.